# War project as a maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, web-services, war, multi-module

I have a multi module maven project with this structure :

```
ParentService
---ChildService-web
---ChildService-webService
```

All the projects are packaged as **war**s.

The web project compiles without any issue.

My problem : I want to write webservices in the webservice project but I need to use The DAO & service layers in the war project and I can't use the web project as a dependency because it's a war.

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Extract those classes into separate module for example `dao` and maybe more separation of concern into another module `service-layer` and so you have usual `jar` which you can use as dependencies...

Comment: Those dependencies for service and DAO ought to be JARs, not WARs.  Easy if you do that.